# Why isn't this javascript while loop running in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop

I'm trying to make it so the program repeatedly accepts input and repeats it back until "exit" is inputted. Right now the loop doesn't run, and I don't know why since the exit variable is set to false. Here's my code:

```
var read = require("read");
var exit = false;


function OutsideLoop (exit) {

while(exit === false){

        read({prompt: "> "}, function (err, result) {

        console.log("");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Type in more input or type 'exit' to close the program.");

        if(result === "exit"){
            exit = true;};
        });


};

};


OutsideLoop();
```

Thanks for the help guys. I have a similar loop working using if/then instead of while, so I rewrote this one along the same lines.

Comment: That is absolutely not how you should prompt.

Comment: You could say `if(!exit)exit = false;` in your `OutsideLoop` function at the very top of your code. Then you won't need to pass the parameter.

Comment: @PHPglue: No, that would still refer to the same `exit`.

Comment: Since there's only one condition to exit the loop, simpler to do `while (exit !== true) {do stuff}`.

Comment: Looks like I have to teach you something again @minitech. when @Ber calls `OutsideLoop()` with no argument it is `undefined`, therefore my comment is correct.

Comment: @PHPglue: Goodness you’re pretentious. That’s pointless. Why wouldn’t you, you know, actually declare a proper variable, like Pointy recommended?

Comment: No, it would make `exit = false;` if the argument is undefined.

Comment: @PHPglue: The argument would always be `undefined`.

Comment: But, `if(result === 'exit'){exit = true;};});` stopping the loop. I voted @Pointy up, by the way. This is simply a comment.

Comment: @PHPglue: That’s why you would declare the variable inside the function, or remove it as an argument.

Comment: I'm not telling @Ber what to do with `var exit`. That's up to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared "exit" as a **parameter** to the function, so the outer declaration has no effect on the logic inside the function. You don't pass anything to the function when you call it, so "exit" is `undefined` and the `===` test fails.

If you either pass "exit" to the function, or else take out the parameter from the function declaration, it'll work — **maybe**. That "read" function is asynchronous, so I'm not sure how node will behave.

Answer (score 1):

Pointy’s right about the parameter shadowing the outer variable you’ve declared. However, what you’ll end up with is a horrible busy loop. Node.js is event-based; use its events properly.

```
function promptUser() {
    read({prompt: "> "}, function(err, result) {
        console.log();
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Type in more input or type 'exit' to close the program.");

        if(result !== "exit") {
            promptUser();
        }
    });
}

promptUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing exit when you call the function. It should be:

```
    OutsideLoop( exit );
```

On the last line.